# Change the object parameter while passing it to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object, let's say "globalObject", which is referenced in many places in code, I shouldn't change this object.
What I need to do is to add property to this object and pass modified object to a function. But I shouldn't really change the object, so that references in code would still reference the non-modified original object.

Should I clone the object like this? :

```
var globalObject = {param1: "something", param2: 42};

// Need to add "param3" to object which will be passed into "foo" function.
// Is cloning object is the only way?
var paramObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, globalObject);
paramObject.param3 = "new param";
foo(paramObject);
```

Is there a better way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quicker like this:

```
foo(jQuery.extend(true, {
    param3: "new param"
}, globalObject);
```

But yes, as far as I'm concearned, cloning the object needs to be involved.

Comment: I like that you're changing parameter without creating additional variable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to clone the object using JSON serilization/deserialization which is fast and reliable. Then, you can add extra properties to the cloned object.

For doing this, you don't need jQuery:

```
var paramObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(globalObject)); //cloning
paramObject.param3 = "new param";
```

Comment: Thanks for useful info.
Yeah, according to these tests:
http://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-jquery-extend
JSON.parse is a bit faster. But, somehow I don't really like that JSON stringifies object and then parses it again. I guess it's just my prejudice.